# librería random de C++11

Tags: c++

No consigo números diferentes...

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>

std::default_random_engine global_urng()
{
    static std::default_random_engine u{};
    return u;
}

void randomize()
{
    static std::random_device rd{};
    global_urng().seed(rd());
} 

int pick(int from, int thru)
{
     static std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{};
     using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
     return d(global_urng(), parm_t{ from, thru });
 }

double pick(double from, double upto)
{
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> d{};
    using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
    return d(global_urng(), parm_t{ from, upto });
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    randomize();
    cout << pick(1, 6) << endl;

}

    cout << "\nLet's roll a continous dice now: ;-)\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    randomize();
    cout << pick(1.0, 6.0) << endl;

}
    return 0;
}
```

En principio lo que tenía que haber compilado sería esto:

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

default_random_engine global_urng();
void randomize();
int pick(int from, int thru);
double pick(double from, double upto);

int main()
{
    randomize();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {

        cout << pick(1, 6) << endl;

    }

    cout << "\nLet's roll a continous dice now: ;-)\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {

        cout << pick(1.0, 6.0) << endl;

    }

}
```

Con este otro archivo:

```
#include<random>


std::default_random_engine& global_urng()
{
    static std::default_random_engine u{};
    return u;
}

void randomize()
{
    static std::random_device rd{};
    global_urng().seed(rd());
}

int pick(int from, int thru)
{
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{};
    using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
    return d(global_urng(), parm_t{ from, thru });
}

double pick(double from, double upto)
{
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> d{};
    using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
    return d(global_urng(), parm_t{ from, upto });
}
```

Por supuesto la programación genérica va más allá de este ejemplo, pero voy a intentar hacerlo igualmente. 
Gracias!

Comment: A mi no me compila el código que has facilitado ¿este es exáctamente el mismo código que te falla?

Comment: A mi tampoco me compila

Comment: En verdad copié el código de un ejemplo en papel pero tuve que añadir parte del código que no venía con el ejemplo, además la versión que compilé y daba siempre los mismos resultados la hice por mi cuenta  en dos ficheros separados...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error en tu código está en `global_urng`. Estás devolviendo un objeto estático por valor, lo cual implica una copia del mismo... el problema está en que si modificas una copia el original no se va a enterar... esa función debería retornar una referencia:

```
std::default_random_engine& global_urng()
{
    static std::default_random_engine u;
    return u;
}
```

Otro problema que tienes es que estás declarando los distribuidores como estáticos:

```
int pick(int from, int thru)
{
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{};
}
```

El problema que esto tiene es que únicamente se inicializarán una vez. No sería problemático si no fuese porque la configuración del rango de valores hay que indicarla necesariamente en el constructor. Es decir, la función tendría que quedar tal que:

```
int pick(int from, int thru)
{
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{from,thru};
  return d(global_urng());
}
```

Pero con este diseño únicamente podrías especificar el rango la primera vez que haces uso de la función. El resto de llamadas no vuelven a inicializar el distribuidor por lo que el rango no va a ser modificado. La versión correcta de la función sería:

```
int pick(int from, int thru)
{
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{from,thru};
  return d(global_urng());
}
```

Además, la función `randomize` no debería tener `rd` como miembro estático, ya que no aporta absolutamente nada.

```
void randomize()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    global_urng().seed(rd());
}
```

Y para rematar, un último problema: Meter una llamada a `randomize` en cada iteración. No sabes cómo funciona el generador, pero si éste genera la semilla a partir de, por ejemplo, los segundos, vas a obtener la misma semilla durante todas las peticiones que hagas en ese segundo, por lo que  va a devolver el mismo número una y otra vez. Si, en cambio, se basa en valores de tu equipo (número de serie de la placa base, por ejemplo), el resultado será que **siempre** te generará el mismo identificador.

Lo correcto es inicializar la semilla únicamente una vez:

```
int main()
{

  randomize();
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
  {
    cout << pick(1, 6) << endl;

  }

  cout << "\nLet's roll a continous dice now: ;-)\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
  {
    cout << pick(1.0, 6.0) << endl;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Con esto ya te funcionaría, ahora que tener dos funciones `pick` cuando hacen exactamente lo mismo es algo totalmente redundante. ¿Cuando necesites trabajar con `char` vas a hacer una tercera versión? ¿Y una cuarta para `unsigned int`? Para atajar este problema existen los templates:

```
template<class TYPE>
struct random_traits;

template<>
struct random_traits<int>
{
    using type = int;
    using distType = std::uniform_int_distribution<>;
};

template<>
struct random_traits<double>
{
    using type = double;
    using distType = std::uniform_real_distribution<>;
};

class RandomGenerator
{
  std::default_random_engine gen;

public:

  RandomGenerator()
    : gen{[]() -> std::random_device::result_type
               { std::random_device rd; return rd(); }()
         }
  {
  }

  std::default_random_engine& operator()()
  { return gen; }
};


template<class TYPE>
typename random_traits<TYPE>::type pick(TYPE from, TYPE to)
{
  static RandomGenerator gen;

  using distType = typename random_traits<TYPE>::distType;
  auto distributor = distType{from,to};
  return distributor(gen());
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
  {
    cout << pick(1, 6) << endl;

  }

  cout << "\nLet's roll a continous dice now: ;-)\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
  {
    cout << pick(1.0, 6.0) << endl;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Lo único que necesitas para ampliar la funcionalidad es crear una especialización de `random_traits` para el nuevo tipo a controlar y listo. Se podría perfeccionar para que fuese más personalizable (por ejemplo para poder elegir el generador a utilizar), pero eso ya corre de tu cuenta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias! El primer error fue por culpa de intellisense de visual studio que me confundió porque se quejaba de la referencia del ejemplo de código original (que solo tengo en papel). Cómo me ofusqué cambié el único randomize() para repetirlo en cada bucle, al corregirlo y ejecutar un solo randomize el programa dio diferentes resultados y en diferentes ejecuciones; agradezco igualmente la disección del código pues apenas tengo nociones de la función rand() de C...¿Sabeis de algun tutorial sencillo de la librería random de C++11? He mirado libros de D.Knuth y peter gottchling pero no me entero...

Comment: ¿Te vale esto? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3551.pdf. La librería es más sencilla de utilizar si tienes un conocimiento previo sobre cómo funciona la generación de números aleatorios.